# How to animate the JavaScript counter

Tags: javascript, html

I am counting values from 0 to 100 in JavaScript, but the whole count should take 3 seconds to reach 0 to 100.but right now its happening withing milliseconds.

how can i do that?

```
<span><span id="counter"> </span> of 100 files</span>


        <script>
            for(var i=0;i<=100;i++)
            {       
                setTimeout(document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = i, 3000);
            }
        </script>
```

Example:

http://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/03-yodaloader.gif

Comment: Why are you setting a ton of intervals

Comment: @AndrewL.opps that was wrong line of code, it was suppose to be setTimeout in my code. just changed it

Comment: So what's wrong with the code?

Comment: @AndrewL. what i want to achieve is the loop should count from 0 to 1 like
0 1 2 3.. and so on till 100, the whole count should take 3 seconds. But now the count is happening within milliseconds its not counting like how i want to.

Comment: ok you want to print 0 to 100 with animation right

Comment: @Dhaarani yes..

Comment: what type of animation you want..

Comment: Use `setInterval`...

Comment: @MithunRaikar How long you'd estimate the `for` loop will take to execute? Then think, how many timeouts are set within the loop, and when the timed functions are executed, considering the timers are launched practically at the same moment, but having the same delay too. What is the solution?

Comment: just like how the value changes below the progress bar.

Comment: Added example..

Comment: ... and also, the syntax of `setTimeout` is wrong. When corrected, it reveals a logical error: `i` will be always `100` at the time when the timed functions are executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean to go from 1 - 100 in 3 seconds, here's an example:

```
var i = 0;

var inv = setInterval(function() {     
    if(i < 100)
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = ++i;
    else
        clearInterval(inv);
}, 3000 / 100);
```

This makes the whole incrementation take about 3 seconds. It's achieved by setting an interval that (prefix) increments global variable `i` and sets as `innerHTML` every 0.03 seconds. It then clears the interval after reaching 100. You can modify step, speed, and bounds to your liking. Here's an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5L20qn04/1/).

Comment: @MithunRaikar no problem :)